# How to create two x-axes label using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

There is a way to create two label for y-axes. But how do you make a multiple x-axes label in chart.js? eg: example as in this picture:
[How to group (two-level) axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSrNv.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated accepted answer to also work with V3 and V4 since scale config has been changed:

```js
var ctx = $("#c");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January;2015", "February;2015", "March;2015", "January;2016", "February;2016", "March;2016"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          callback: function(label) {
            let realLabel = this.getLabelForValue(label)
            var month = realLabel.split(";")[0];
            var year = realLabel.split(";")[1];
            return month;
          }
        }
      },
      xAxis2: {
        type: "category",
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function(label) {
            let realLabel = this.getLabelForValue(label)

            var month = realLabel.split(";")[0];
            var year = realLabel.split(";")[1];
            if (month === "February") {
              return year;
            } else {
              return "";
            }
          }
        }
      },
      y: {

        beginAtZero: true

      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: This solution also works on version 4.2.1 of Chart JS. =)

Answer (score 33):

### For v2 only (v3 see @LeeLenalee's answer)

This question has already been answered on github [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2138)

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hamalainen/6c0L1yva/3/)

```js
var ctx = $("#c");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January;2015", "February;2015", "March;2015", "January;2016", "February;2016", "March;2016"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      xAxisID:'xAxis1',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options:{
    scales:{
      xAxes:[
        {
          id:'xAxis1',
          type:"category",
          ticks:{
            callback:function(label){
              var month = label.split(";")[0];
              var year = label.split(";")[1];
              return month;
            }
          }
        },
        {
          id:'xAxis2',
          type:"category",
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
          },
          ticks:{
            callback:function(label){
              var month = label.split(";")[0];
              var year = label.split(";")[1];
              if(month === "February"){
                return year;
              }else{
                return "";
              }
            }
          }
        }],
      yAxes:[{
        ticks:{
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not supported in ChartJs V3

Comment: see @LeeLenalee's answer for v3

Answer (score 5):

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [20, 50, 100, 75, 25, 0],
      label: "Left dataset",

      // This binds the dataset to the left y axis
      yAxisID: "left-y-axis",
    }, {
      data: [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 0],
      label: "Right dataset",

      // This binds the dataset to the right y axis
      yAxisID: "right-y-axis",
    }],
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: "left-y-axis",
        type: "linear",
        position: "left",
      }, {
        id: "right-y-axis",
        type: "linear",
        position: "right",
      }],
    }, 
  },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

okay maby a bit late ;)

how can we show the last tick in the second x-axis row?

with the code from above, we return a empty string.
i want to see the label of the last point.

```
      ticks:{
        callback:function(label){
          var month = label.split(";")[0];
          var year = label.split(";")[1];
          if(month === "February"){
            return year;
          }else{
            return "";  **<==== ???**
          }
```

thx for the help.

EDIT

i change it a bit but not complete like i will
i don't want the label at 30 and 31 just the last day
w.a.w 31 label , 30 not a label

month ended at 30 => label

```
            return month;
          }else if 
            (Nbrday === "31"){
            return month;
          }else if 
            (Nbrday === "30"){
            return month;
          }
            else{
              // return month;
            return "";
```