# Chartjs - data format for bar chart with multi-level x-axes

Tags: chart.js

Input data

```
Engine,Car,Brand,Efficiency
ABC212,Toyota Corolla,Toyota,1.95
ABC212,Toyota Yaris,Toyota,1.94
ABC212,Totyota Etios,Toyota,1.93
ABC212,Honda City,Honda,1.93
ABC212A,Honda Brio,Honda,1.91
DEF311,Toyota Camry,Toyota,1.90
DEF310,Toyota Prius,Toyota,1.82
DEF310,Ford Explorer,Ford,1.85
DEF310,Ford Endeavour,Ford,1.83
DEF305,Ford Fugo,Ford,1.79
```

With data like above, I need to create a chart in `ChartJs` with multi-level x-axes. An expected output created using MS excel pivot chart is as below. Here the efficiency of each model is plotted as a bar. Bars in each group is sorted in the descending order of the efficiency value. How should I create the data for this kind of chart ?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934853/3551786)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I have made such graph in my POC , where I used :

```
data: {
      labels: ["ABC212", "ABC212A",...],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "ABC212",
          data: [val1, val2,....]
        }, {
          label: "ABC212A",
          data: [val3, val4,...]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being confident that this is the simplest solution, I provide some example where I use a second axis, containing labels for the groups, but in a scaled-up array, for correct alignment.

The only problem is that if you enable rotation for the group `maxRotation>0`, the text will always be rotated, since (due to scaling) it is bound to a very small area.

https://jsfiddle.net/h6z4apvo/

```
var myData = [
  ["ABC212","Toyota Corolla","Toyota",1.95],
  ["ABC212","Toyota Yaris","Toyota",1.94],
  ["ABC212","Totyota Etios","Toyota",1.93],
  ["ABC212","Honda City","Honda",1.93],
  ["ABC212A","Honda Brio","Honda",1.91],
  ["DEF311","Toyota Camry","Toyota",1.90],
  ["DEF310","Toyota Prius","Toyota",1.82],
  ["DEF310","Ford Explorer","Ford",1.85],
  ["DEF310","Ford Endeavour","Ford",1.83],
  ["DEF305","Ford Fugo","Ford",1.79]
];

/*Calculates group labels to a scaled array so that they can align better*/
function calculateGroupLabels(data){
  const scaleFactor=100;
  var labels = _(data)
  .groupBy((elem)=>elem[0])
  .map((entriesOnSameGroup, key)=>{
      var newSize = entriesOnSameGroup.length*scaleFactor;
      var newArray = new Array(newSize);
      newArray[0]="";
      newArray[newArray.length-1]="";
      newArray[parseInt((newArray.length-1)/2)]=key;
      return newArray;
  }).flatten().value()

  return labels;
}


var labels = calculateGroupLabels(myData);

var ctx = $("#c");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      xAxisID:'modelAxis',
      data: myData.map((entry)=>entry[3])
    }]
  },
  options:{
    scales:{
      xAxes:[
        {
          id:'modelAxis',
          type:"category",
          ticks:{
            //maxRotation:0,
            autoSkip: false,
            callback:function(label, x2, x3, x4){
              console.log("modelAxis", label, x2, x3, x4)
              return label;
            }
                   },
         labels:myData.map((entry=>entry[1]))
        },
        {
          id:'groupAxis',
          type:"category",
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
          },
          ticks:{
            padding:0,
            maxRotation:0,
            autoSkip: false,
            callback:function(label){
                return label;
            }
          },
          labels:labels

        }],
      yAxes:[{
        ticks:{
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```