# Two different x axis labels on line chart, chart.js react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I'm trying to create a chart component for weather in React using chart.js. I want two different x axis with the temp above the chart, and the times below the chart. The data is correct in how I wan't it, I just want to use two different labels along the top and the bottom of the x axis.
How would I do this?

```
import React from "react";
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

class WeatherOverview extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: {
                labels: ['15:00', '18:00', '21:00', '00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00'], //time
                datasets: [{
                    data: [18, 19, 18, 16, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18] //temp
                }],
            }
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="chart">
                <Line
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                    options={{
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    drawOnChartArea: false
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    suggestedMin: 13, // lowest from data minus 2/3
                                    display: false 
                                }
                            }],
                            xAxes: [
                                {
                                    gridLines: {
                                        drawOnChartArea: false
                                    },
                                },
                                { position: 'top' },
                            ]
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default WeatherOverview;
```

Comment: look at that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934608/how-to-create-two-x-axes-label-using-chart-js this is what you are looking for?

Comment: That looks like it should work @DavidPeer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this ref her:

[How to create two x-axes label using chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934608/how-to-create-two-x-axes-label-using-chart-js)

it looks like what you are asking about.

enjoy!